# What is the best way to transfer data between CEP engine and stream data generator with in LAN?

Tags: java, complex-event-processing

I'm new to Complex event processing(CEP) systems, using one of the CEP engine called Esper to detect event patterns in smart buildings. Different sensors assumed and implemented data generators for them.
I would like to measure performance of my system. Whole implementation is in java so what is the best way to transfer stream data from different data generators to my CEP system with in LAN.

should I use UDP or TCP ??
Threading is required? because of many sensors assumed.

Answer (score 0):

You asked your question many months ago, but I will make some comments anyway. From what I read, it seems to me that (as of March 2015...)

- the ingest protocol to use is AMQP
- data flow and scaling should be managed by Apache Storm or Spark
- for resilience, use some sort of message queue - e.g. RabbitMQ, Kafka, Azure EventHubs, AWS Kinesis

I'm pretty sure you can use all these technologies from the Java ecosystem.